# Loop through nested containers inside a container in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, components

So, I'm working on this application where I have `JPanel` objects populate an outer panel. I would like to loop through the panels (since they are being inserted dynamically, I don't know how many there are going to be) inside of the outer panel and access their Components. However, there only seems to be `.getComponentCount()` and `getComponent()` defined for panel and it does not allow me to look for it's nested components.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pl.playlistDisplay.getComponentCount(); i++)
{
    //  for(int j = 0; j < pl.playlistDisplay.getComponent(i).getComponentCount())   //line with the problem
    pl.playlistDisplay.getComponent(i).setForeground(baseColor);
}
```

Is there something like .getContainerCount() that I could use instead? or any other way to be able to access the components of nested containers?

Comment: *"ince they are being inserted dynamically, I don't know how many there are going to be"*  Keep a count!

Comment: @AndrewThompson , Thanks for the tip, I will. But I still can't access them through that method.

Comment: @Dauta: as per my answer, you would need recursion. and as per my answer, **don't** do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Container class has a `getComponentCount()` method, and you could call `instanceof` to see if your `Component` is a `Container`, cast it to `Container`, call this method, and then recursively this way go through the container/component tree until you find the `JPanel` of interest – but why put yourself through the risk and trouble when much better solutions are at hand?

Simply keep references of the components of interest and access them that way.  And even if components are added during run-time, there's no reason not to be able to set up your code to easily and safely store a reference to it if need be. This will be a much more robust solution than trying to walk through a component tree as you're doing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: No problem, and thanks for the improvements.

Comment: @Dauta: if still stuck, please make your question more concrete.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Works like a charm! Yeah, I know the question is a little vague, but I wanted to know if thing like that was possible in principle. Thanks for your help, gentlemen.